# trying to start a countdown again when time is up

Tags: jquery, loops, countdowntimer

I'm using [jQuery.countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#install) and I'm trying to make it so that after the countdown is finished it restarts with another date I want to restart every friday. so it counts down all week and when it hits friday it gives a message and then waits a lil amount of time then restarts. I know how to do the first countdown but I am having problem getting the countdown to start again. Don't know what do do with setting flag variables or how to use a loop in this case. here is a relevent piece of code that doesnt work .

I set `var again = false` (you don't see it in the snippet i realize) in the global context. then check to see if its false and if the new date < then the str. str gets updated in the function that says what do when finished. In my original code i had `str` set to the first future date and put that as a parameter in the `countdown method` I just put in `"2015/7/27 23:49:10"` for testing. How can i set the timer again? I think i need some kind of loop mechanism.

```
    if(again == false && new Date() < new Date(str)){
            $('#clock').countdown("2015/7/27 23:49:10") .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
              var format = '%D days %H hours %M mminutes %S seconds';
                   $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
                      again = true
                     })
                     .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
                            if(again == true){
                                 $(this).html('This offer has expired!');
                                      str = "2015/7/27 23:49:39"
                                     window.setTimeout(function(){again = false},5000) 
                                     again = false;
                                     console.log(str)  
                            }


                     })                        
       }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you post your full relevant codes, may be in jsfiddle ..

Comment: hi. Im wondering if I can do something like set a variable inside a setTimeout  in the snippet , would the variable  `again` be set to false after 5 secs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `setTimeout` you can re-initialize it. You have something called `event.elapsed` to check whether time is elapsed or not and there will not be any need of `finish.countdown`. **[Example from site](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/count-up.html)**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/prkkuqqL/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date='2015/07/29 12:29:00';//change this to very near time and elapse and check it
    var format='%D days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds';                
    $('#clock').countdown(date)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event){
         $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
    }).on('finish.countdown',function(event){
           var ev=event;
           var ctrl=$(this);
           $(ctrl).html('This offer has expired!');
           window.setTimeout(function(){
              $('#clock').countdown('2015/12/20 12:34:56'); //change this date accordingly
           },5000)
    })
});
```

Comment: hi, the snippet in http://jsfiddle.net/prkkuqqL/1/ stops at 1 second left and the counter doesn't start again. thanks for you response

Comment: The snippet you gave doesn't work at all!! There isnt any plugins referred in the fiddle!!

Comment: sorry. Ill try to put the plugin into the fiddle. I knew the fiddle wasn't going work. I just copied it from my editor

Comment: I can't find a cdn. there is github raw as an external source used in http://jsfiddle.net/prkkuqqL/2/.  you prob wont see the demo because fiddle says they don't want us to use github. if you find the cdn and show me that it works that would be great. other wise thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2537537.. No need to `re-initialize` Just check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/prkkuqqL/3/)**

Comment: did you check to see if it starts again when the countdown is finished. It doesn't look like it does. It looks like it stops at one second and doesn't start again.

Comment: that's cs I've explicitly set `event.elapse` to `true`.. Keep it for some low time and remove `event.elapse=true`

Comment: @user2537537 Updated answer with working demo!! check it!!

Comment: yay :). I'm so glad it works.I'm wondering why you decided not to use elapse Mode. It was prob the wrong tool for the jobs. I think that people would think it's the right one since it sounds like you could do something when time elapses. maybe you could but it looks like from the demo that it just "continues counting." now i got i hope i will be able to insert the dates dynamically without a prob. Thank you for your time and solution,

Comment: It din work for me when I used elapse Mode!! even I was wondering!! Its stayed there and did not went inside `update.countdown` event. So I just removed it and tried this! Probably some bug!! not sure though!! Anyways!! Happy coding!! Glad it helped you.. :)

Comment: You saved my day.
If someone want more check my codepen https://codepen.io/santanup789/pen/gOLBJWo?editors=1010 with dynamic countdown every year.